# select in query where criteria in textfield

Tags: sql, ms-access

I m having a textfield in ms-access which has values

54551,54550

now i m writing a query as:

```
SELECT * from [work_log1] w where w.[activity_id] in (forms![bai multiple]!text1);
```

which works fine when the textfield has the value "54551"

but does not work when the textfield has the values "54551,54550"

anything that can be done such that the values can be kept somewhere to work.

Regards

Comment: are trying to match the number 54551,54550 or the string of that number.  If match a number I would remove the comma and try it that way

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because "54551,54550" value is taken as a single string so it tries to match it exactly not "54551" and "54550" as two seperate entries

Comment: so how can this can be rectified, any other solution?

Comment: try splitting the string with `,`

Comment: access does not support splitting in sql?